# "Most" is used as an adjective and an adverb

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, word-order

I read a sentence " He gave the most money". In this sentence "most" is used as an adjective. If I want to use "most" as an adverb can I say "He gave money the most" Is the latter correct grammar? and if it is does it sound natural?

Thank you :-)

Comment: In your example, "most" is a determiner, not an adjective. Your second example is probably ungrammatical. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: I think the former "most" is superlative adjective because it describes the noun money. Regarding the latter, I'm curious because when using superlative adverb "most",  you usually use it after a verb which in this case is "gave money". If there were 3 people who gave money and one person gave the most so wouldn't "He gave money the most" be correct grammar?

Comment: No, "most" is **never** an adjective: see here: [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/most). In your example, "most" is a superlative determiner used to determine the noun "money", cf. "**much** money" (plain) ~"**more** money (comparative) ~ "**most** money" (superlative). As I told you, your other example may be ungrammatical, but in any case it would still be a determiner

Comment: I believe "most" can be used as superlative adjectives        https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives                                                      https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/most                                                http://www.dictionary.com/browse/most.                                              but any way, going back to my original question which is about superlative adverb "most"  for ex. John sang 2 songs, Mike sang 3 songs and Peter sang 4 songs, so wouldn't it be correct to say Peter sang songs the most?

Comment: Using that grammar, Peter(noun) , sang (verb) , songs (noun) and the most(adverb) could we also say He gave money the most.             He(noun) gave(verb) money(noun) the most(adverb)?

Comment: No, I'm sorry but you are wrong. We stopped calling such words adjectives many years ago when the word "determiner" came into popular use. I just told you that "most" would still be a determiner even in your other example, it still means "most money". "Most" is only an adverb when it modifies adjectives ("most expensive") or adverbs ("most tactfully").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59413/discussion-between-billj-and-user54219).

Answer (score 4):

"He gave the most money" and "He gave money the most" mean two different things.  The first is a comparison to others giving money.  The second is a comparison to other things he gives.

In sum, it's grammatical.  It's natural.  But watch for meaning.